Remove the namespace from .net core 8 soap service using SoapCore
I have a wcf soap (let's say OldService) service written in asp.net framework. And I have to rewrite the service in asp.net core 8 (let's say NewService) using SoapCore Library.
The NewService must follow the same data contracts and operation contracts that are used in the OldService.
The OldService (.net framework), when imported using SoapUI for example, it has a method "Test". The request is:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:abc="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC.Models.Contracts">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:Test>
         <tem:player>
            <abc:Detail>
               <Age>?</Age>
            </abc:Detail>
            <abc:Name>?</abc:Name>
         </tem:player>
      </tem:Test>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

You see the Age attribute has no namespace. This is done by adding [DataContract(Namespace = "")] on PlayerDetailsContract class.
The problem is: in the NewService (.net core), I could not remove the namesapce from the Age attribute. SoapCore does not allow [DataContract(Namespace = "")] on PlayerDetailsContract class. It throws: ArgumentException: Cannot use a prefix with an empty namespace.
my code is:
 [ServiceContract]
 public interface IMyService
 {
     [OperationContract]
     Task<bool> Test(PlayerContract player);
 }


public class MyService: IMyService
{
    public async Task<bool> Test(PlayerContract player)
    {
        return true;
    }
}


    [DataContract]
    public class PlayerContract
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public PlayerDetailsContract Detail { get; set; }
    }

    public class PlayerDetailsContract
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }



You need a Uri with a default namespace like xmls="http://.............." when you use a namespace "".   XML when no namespace is used it automatically take the namespace of the parent node.
